# Example of three Bernoulli random variables X, Y, Z that are not independent but E[XYZ]=E[X]E[Y]E[Z]

Tags: probability, self-study, mean, independence, bernoulli-distribution

Stuck with this challenge my professor gives us. Does anyone have a good example? I've seen examples for two variables, not for three though. Here is the full problem:

Give example of Bernoulli random variables $X,Y,Z$ which are not independent, $E[X]=E[Y]=E[Z]=1/2$, and $E[XYZ]=E[X]·E[Y]·E[Z]$.

Comment: Could you illustrate the 2 variable problem? It could provide some useful insights for the 3 variable problem. Also, since this is homework, please tag `self-study`

Comment: It is not the case for only two Bernouilli random variables. See https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/check-my-proof-on-showing-two-bernoulli-rvs-are-independent.446924/ or see that if following the method in my answer that there would be a consistent linear system of four equations and only four free variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement $E[XYZ]=E[X]E[Y]E[Z]$ is the same as $P(X=1, Y=1, Z=1)=0.125$. Given the other requirements, $P(X=1)=0.5$, $P(Y=1)=0.5$ and $P(Z=1)=0.5$ (and the fact that the total probability should add up to 1) we can establish a set of equations. Let $P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)=p_{x,y,z}$ and we can write

$$
p_{1,1,1}=0.125\\
p_{1,0,0}+p_{1,0,1}+p_{1,1,0}+p_{1,1,1}=0.5\\
p_{0,1,0}+p_{0,1,1}+p_{1,1,0}+p_{1,1,1}=0.5\\
p_{0,0,1}+p_{0,1,1}+p_{1,0,1}+p_{1,1,1}=0.5\\
p_{0,0,0}+p_{0,0,1}+p_{0,1,0}+p_{1,0,0}+p_{0,1,1}+p_{1,0,1}+p_{0,1,1}+p_{1,1,1}=1
$$
To find an example, we have to find a solution to the above set of equations,that satisfy  that all $p$'s are between 0 and 1, but for which at least one of the $p_{x,y,z}\neq 0.125$. And after looking a little I found the solution:

$$
 p_{1,1,1}=1/8\\
p_{1,0,0}=p_{0,1,1}=1/4,\\
p_{0,1,0}=p_{0,0,1}=p_{1,1,0}=p_{1,0,1}=1/16\\
p_{0,0,0}=1/8.
$$

Comment: The solution is simpler than you suggest, because the required condition only is that $\Pr(X=1,Y=1,Z=1)=E[XYZ]=E[X]E[Y]E[Z]=(1/2)^3.$ Thus, *all* you have to do is distribute the remaining probability of $1-1/2^3 = 7/8$ among the other seven possible outcomes in an uneven way. Indeed, if you did this *randomly* there is a 100% chance that $(X,Y,Z)$ would not be independent!

Comment: @whuber But what you suggest would not satisfy the requirement that $EX=EY=EX=1/2$ .

Comment: While I can see this is clearly a solid answer, my professor was more looking for a specific/real world example. I am still struggling to come up with something that might model this behavior. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Since all probabilities in the example are of the form 1/2^n, n<5 it is possible to describe it with four coin tosses, but I am not sure how natural it will seem; for example let X Y and Z be coin tosses. If all three are heads or all three are tails, do nothing. If they are different, throw another coin. If the other coin says head turn Y and Z to the opposite of X. This should produce the probabilities above

Comment: @Jarle Thank you, I overlooked that expectation requirement, so that rules out the random solution.